# How did Riddick kill Lord Marshal Zhylaw?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-chronicles-of-riddick

Both [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Riddick#Plot) and [wikia](http://riddick.wikia.com/wiki/Zhylaw#The_Sixth_Regime:_Zhylaw_the_Last) just say that the boss managed to evade a hit by Vaako, but could not save himself rom Riddick's dagger right after that. However, when I watched the movie, it clearly [looked](https://youtu.be/UrMcfE7kz84?t=225) to me like if Lord Marshal found himself in such a position that he was able to choose how to die, therefore to whom transfer his lordship, and chose Riddick.

Do I over-think that scene or am I right?

Answer (score 3):

**He wasn't choosing die**...he was clearly evading Vaako's weapon while trying to reach for the discarded spear he pulled from his back.

Unfortunately for him, when he got there, Riddick was in the way with his foot on it.

[image]

**He was taken by surprise**.... not giving up. That's the expression you're seeing.